# submit a like to a post by API with c # facebook

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the facebook api for c #, and I'm trying to make a post like the one I received previously.

my code like this:

```
    public void FazLike(CPerfis user, string idobject)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient(user.token);
        dynamic resp = fb.Post("/{0}/likes", idobject);
    }
```

CPerfis is a class where I have user data  like the  token.

but i get an error that says:

> Parameter count mismatch.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current 
>   web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException:
>   Parameter count mismatch.

I already tested this code is not the facebook page and resulted. I used the token and id_object I have saved, and I got a true facebook, and like the post is done.

what am I doing wrong? or is there another way to submit the Like

Comment: I already solved my problem :)
I made the following change and is already working well

public void FazLike(CPerfis _perfil, string idobject)
        {
            FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(_perfil.Atoken);
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.idobject = "";
            dynamic resp = fb.Post(idobject + "/likes", parameters);
        }